# Sending/receiving SMS using coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, sms

What are my options for sending an SMS using coldfusion? I've done a bit of research, but it's not a common language so I'm not finding a lot. So far, here are the three options I've come up with:

Sending an email to phone#@carrier.com. I don't want to do this, because I have to know my customer's carriers and I'm not sure I'd be able to receive replies.

Use a 3rd party gateway, such as Plivo. This may or may not be my best option. I was hoping to avoid any long-term costs in this project though.

Install a GSM Modem on my server - this is the one I'm curious about. Can coldfusion do this? Are there costs after the modem? How does it work exactly?

Comment: Sounds like you already know the answer. Either use email (which requires knowing the carrier) or use an SMS provider.  I am not familiar with the GSM modem route, but in addition to adding a lot more complexity, but from what I have read it sounds like it still requires a paid provider. If so, it is simpler to go the api/gateway route.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest a service like Twilio that let you send SMS etc. With todays technology plus cloud based services, its better to use providers rather than reinventing the wheel.

HTH

AH.

Comment: This is about what I had expected.

Comment: Ok great. Please confirm as right answer if this suggestion guides you in right direction.

Answer (score 4):

CF has been able to send SMS via an Event Gateway for a while now.

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-external-resources/using-the-sms-event-gateway/configuring-an-sms-event-gateway.html

https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-external-resources/using-the-sms-event-gateway/coldfusion-sms-development-tools.html

Comment: Where do I get/find more about an SMS event gateway?

Comment: Were the two links not helpful?

Comment: They are helpful in explaining how to configure and use a gateway, but they do not tell me what a gateway is or where to find one.

Comment: Event Gateways are built into CF, you don't have to find one. You just have to learn how to create them: https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-external-resources/using-event-gateways/about-event-gateways.html

Comment: Either way I'll need some way to send the sms messages, right? A carrier or something similar?

Comment: I've never done it before in my life, but a google search string of `send text message from coldfusion 10` led me to sample code in less than a minute/

Comment: Ben Nadel has some examples: https://www.bennadel.com/blog/692-sending-text-messages-sms-with-coldfusion-and-cfmail.htm

Comment: @JamesAMohler - True, but that requires knowing the phone number carrier. IMO, using a 3rd party API would be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

CF admin link to configure a new gateway:
http:///CFIDE/administrator/eventgateway/gateways.cfm

Sample code for cfm to send sms:

```
<cftry>
  <cfscript>
    VARIABLES.cellNumList ='xxxxxxxxxx'; //CellNumber list
    VARIABLES.msg = structNew();
    VARIABLES.msg.command = "submit";
    VARIABLES.msg.destAddress = VARIABLES.cellNumList;
    VARIABLES.msg.shortMessage = 'Test National 2';
    VARIABLES.msg.registeredDelivery = "0";
    VARIABLES.msg.ProtocolId = 'Version3_4';
    VARIABLES.msg.SourceAddressTon = '2';
    VARIABLES.msg.SourceAddressNpi = 'Unknown';
    VARIABLES.msg.DestinationAddress = VARIABLES.cellNumList;
    VARIABLES.msg.DestinationAddressTon = '0';
    VARIABLES.msg.DestinationAddressNpi = 'Unknown';
    VARIABLES.msg.DataCoding = 'Latin1';
    VARIABLES.result = sendGatewayMessage('GATEWAY INSTANCE ID', VARIABLES.msg);
  </cfscript>
  <cfcatch type="any" >
    <cfoutput>#CFCATCH.message#</cfoutput>
  </cfcatch>
</cftry>
```